# Javascript file not loading in android webview. Loads on mobile browser and desktop browser

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, webview

As the title says, the Javascript of a certain page is not being executed. It does work on desktop and the mobile browser but not in the webview. As far as I understand I have enabled javascript.

**Code**

```
package com.example.eduquiz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://eduquizitmda.000webhostapp.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        
    }

    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after a lot of trial and error. I needed to add webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);